# How do I get back my files marked as deleted in the unstaged changes area of Git staging?

Tags: eclipse, egit

I'm running Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1 with egit for versioning. I've been using eclipse and egit for just a few months and am not up on all of it's intricacies yet. I've found some related questions here for git, but I don't really understand how to use egit to accomplish what the answers propose.

The immediate problem I have is that no files are visible in the project tree except for the libraries and WEB-INF under war. The files show up in the unstaged changes area of the Git staging window marked with an x as deleted. This is a jsp project running google app engine if it matters.

What got me to this point was attempting to checkout the master branch. I got an error saying the branch could not find 2 files and afterwards my working files in the current branch disappeared. The Git repositories view shows my current branch is the same as the one I had been working on, so these files should normally be visible.

Since I never chose to delete these files I have no idea what stage egit thinks it's in. I don't have a backup and my other branches haven't had recent changes merged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always see the state of Git as a text decoration next to each repository node in the repositories view of the Git perspective. Normally that should only show the branch name, but it might also be something like "Interactive rebase", if Git stops for user input in the middle of an operation.

If that is not showing the branch name you want, then just the context menu Switch->[branchname] should bring you back to the wanted branch.

If everything else fails, you can always throw away all local changes and have your local working directory reset to the state of any commit (or branch) by using context menu->Reset->Hard and select the commit (or branch) to which you want to reset. Be aware that this wipes out any uncommitted local changes.

In case of more questions, you should read the very detailed [EGit user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide).

Comment: Thanks @Bananeweizen. I have no text decoration, just the staged for removal tag in the unstaged changes of the staging window. The repository view shows a check decoration on the branch I want to be in. Will wiping out uncommitted local changes with a hard reset restore the lost files or just clear the unstaged changes window? I think the EGit user guide says it will restore my files, but never having done a reset before, plus not knowing how git got into this state in the first place, makes me want to err on the side of caution.

Comment: I would vote up your answer but don't the reputation yet to do that.

Comment: I took @Bananeweizen's advice and did a hard reset of the current branch. EGit restored the missing files with no issues. I still don't know what caused the strange state EGit got into.